# React referencing const outside of class

Tags: reactjs

I'm very new to React, so this might be a stupid question. But I'm making tabs. And I decided to split the content of the tabs into separate `const`. The issue is that now I can no longer reference anything in tabs content that I declared in the class section. I'm obviously doing something wrong. Can someone please take a look and let me know what I need to fix here?

Here's the basic outline of my code. How do I reference company inside the `GeneralContent const`? Do I need to declare it elsewhere? When I reference it inside my class, it works.

```
class Tabs extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activeLocation: 0,

      activeTabIndex: 0,
      initialData: [
        {
          label: "General",
          content: <GeneralContent />
        }
      ]
    };
    this.handleTabClick = this.handleTabClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleTabClick(index) {
    this.setState({
      activeTabIndex: index
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { initialData, activeTabIndex } = this.state;
    const activeItem = this.state.initialData[activeTabIndex];

    const { company } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <article>
          <div>
            <NavBar />
            <div className="container">
              <Tabs
                handleTabClick={this.handleTabClick}
                data={this.state.initialData}
                activeTabIndex={activeTabIndex}
              />
              <Content content={activeItem.content} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const GeneralContent = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>{company.name}</h1>
  </div>
);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor, you could add the company as prop to `GeneralContent`

```
initialData: [
        {
          label: "General",
          content: <GeneralContent company={props.company}/>
        }
      ]
```

This is not a good practice due to your `GeneralContent` will not be aware of if the company changes. You can address this by using `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
 if(prevProps.company.name !== this.props.company.name) {
    const tabData = [...this.state.initialData];
    tabData.find((tab) => tab.label === 'General');
    tabData.content = <GeneralContent company={this.props.company} />;

    this.setState({initialData: tabData});
 }
}
```

This updates you`General` tab with the new `company`. As you see it is a little "complicated" to maintain.

**I would refactor** the code to avoid doing that, something like this:

```
class Tabs extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {      
      activeTabIndex: 0,      
    };
    this.handleTabClick = this.handleTabClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleTabClick(index) {
    this.setState({
      activeTabIndex: index
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { activeTabIndex } = this.state;

    const tabData = [
      {
        label: "General",
        content: <GeneralContent company={this.props.company}/>
      }
    ];

    const tabContent = tabData[activeTabIndex];

    return (
      <div>
        <article>
          <div>
            <NavBar />
            <div className="container">
              <Tabs
                handleTabClick={this.handleTabClick}
                data={tabData}
                activeTabIndex={activeTabIndex}
              />
              <Content content={tabContent} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const GeneralContent = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>{company.name}</h1>
  </div>
);
```

Basically, the tabs generation has been moved to your `render` method.

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate it. This clarifies a lot!